# How to run celery beat where each task has individual queues?

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I have a Django project with multiple celery beat tasks , I have an issue when  I have multiple celery beat tasks with individual queues so is there a possibility that i can run all these at a time , what is the best practice to run these?

```js
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projectDemon.settings')
app = Celery('projectDemon')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):

    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(minute=30, hour='7'),
        task1.s('Checking task1 !'),
                    queue= 'task1',
                    options={
                        'queue': 'task1',
                        'routing_key': 'task1'}
    )
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(minute=00, hour='6'),
        task2.s('Checking task2 !'),
                queue= 'task2',
                options={
                    'queue': 'task2',
                    'routing_key': 'task2'}
    )
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(
        minute='*/1',  # run every minute
    ),
        task3.s('Checking task3 !'),
            queue= 'task3',
            options={
                'queue': 'task3',
                'routing_key': 'task3'}

        )


@app.task
def task1(arg):
    print(arg)



@app.task
def task2(arg):
    print(arg)



@app.task
def task3(arg):
    print(arg)
```

Comment: Could you possibly expand on what your problem is? I can answer based on the way that I do this (which is different), but I am uncertain on what issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

The way that I handle this is by defining [task_routes](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) where I define each task that is going to use a specific queue. I have certain tasks that are always going to use a specific queue, whether it is triggered from the application as a whole or through celery beat. (Take note that any task that you do not define in the task route will use the default queue).

From there, I simply define celery beat as a scheduler to call specific tasks (without passing the queue as a variable).

I haven't had any problems with this solution, but if you explain your specific problem I may be able to better help.

Comment: Thanks for your time , I have problem with launching multiple terminals and running the commands can't I do it with one single command

Comment: If you have multiple queues, then you will need a worker for each queue. If you want to use a single command, my suggestion would be to use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) which would allow you to start and manage your tasks at once. [Here's](https://medium.com/@channeng/celery-scheduler-part-2-managing-celery-with-supervisor-2a0c6e7f7a6e) some [links](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/extra/supervisord) with examples.